# How to handle destroy edge cases

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say for example you have two users looking at a page. Both click to delete the same record. Is there a 'rails way' to handle these types of edge cases?

I haven't been able to find out how rails handles this but I know that, by default, whoever clicks later will end up with a record not found error. How can you catch this and know it came from a destroy action on a record that was already deleted?

Comment: There is no "Rails" way; you simply need to recover gracefully from the "record not found" error.

Comment: I can do that fairly easily but how can I catch that the source of "record not found" was from attempting to delete a record that was already destroyed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any approach that checks for the record's existence will be subject to a race condition. Eg.

```
@record = Record.find_by_id(params[:id])
if @record
   # I got there first! Or did I?...
   @record.destroy!
```

If the record is destroyed by another request after the existence test, `destroy!` will raise an exception.

You could simply handle the exceptions as they occur:

```
def destroy
  @record = Record.find(params[:id])
  @record.destroy!
  flash[:message] = "Record was destroyed"
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  flash[:message] = "Record was already destroyed"
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed
  flash[:message] = "Record was not destroyed"
end
```

In practice, there generally isn't a reason to do this unless the destroy can actually fail in *both* requests, for example, if there is a callback that prevents the record from being destroyed. And in that case, you probably need more extensive error handling to communicate the reason for the failure back to the client.

For most applications I've seen, just routing the user back to a safe place in the event of a failure is enough.

Comment: I can't get ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound to ever trigger if I got the record, put a breakpoint before destroy!, delete it in mysql, then resume execution. It just works on Rails without error.

Comment: @GuillaumePerrot I think this is because under the hood ActiveRecord eventually just runs SQL "DELETE" with the row ID, and when there is no record with that ID it simply returns an empty set. The exception might be triggered by other conditions, like a foreign key constraint, database connection error, or a failure in a model callback. Rails is emulating the behavior of the database here--no row with that ID, no error.

Answer (score 0):

or

```
def destroy
  @record = Record.find_by(id:params[:id])
  if @record
    @record.destroy!
    flash[:message] = "Record is destroyed"
  else
    flash[:message] = "Record not found!"
  end
end
```

also you can have this in your application_controller.rb, to handle all such request, it will apply to all resource.

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :record_not_found

    private
        def record_not_found
            flash[:danger] = "Record not Found!"
            redirect_to root_path
        end
```

but again, now you should use find() to raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound if record not found

Comment: I have the rescue already in place but a generic "Record not Found!" Error isn't descriptive to the user at all. The exact same error pops up if you try to URL-access a file that doesn't exist. How do I catch the *source* of the RecordNotFound